# Ultraviolet + Textmate for Ruby? How do I use this?

Tags: ruby, textmate

Ok so I've had my Macbook for 3-days now.

I installed textmate and saw the cool Ruby syntax highlighting thing called Ultraviolet.

I've installed the ultraviolet gem, but I don't get what it does. How exactly do I use it? Or is it installed automatically? Is there supposed to be an ultraviolet theme? What exactly does ultraviolet DO?

Comment: I was under the impression it would give me a new theme, but I don't see a theme called ultraviolet anywhere in Preferences > Colors

Comment: Or did ultraviolet create all these themes for me? I never checked prior, so I don't know if these ones were already here by default..

Answer (score 3):

[Ultraviolet](http://ultraviolet.rubyforge.org/) is a syntax highlighting engine used in ruby apps. Combined with Textpow, it allows you to render the same syntax highlighting that you see in textmate on to things like web pages.

Textmate ships with plenty themes you can choose from (vibrant ink is probably the most popular one), ultraviolet leverages those themes.